# How to change URLs of Mini-Calendar Block View?

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm using the calendar module in drupal 7. I put the block-view mini-calendar but I want to make a change to the URL of each day's link of the month that showing me.

By default, the URL sent me to the full schedule of activities in that month (use event_calendar content type). However, I want to change that view and I just want to make a simple listing of activities for the month.

How I can change the URL to do access the new view I want to create?

Sorry for my english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this might be helpful to you http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/08/07/drupal-customize-the-day-link-inside-the-mini-calendar-navigation-block/

Comment: Dvex let me add this as answer instead of comment so else no one miss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes a well description for altering date links in calendar http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/08/07/drupal-customize-the-day-link-inside-the-mini-calendar-navigation-block/

Comment: Can you help me with other question, please? http://bit.ly/19D6Yg3

Answer (score 1):

In mini-calendar view go to advanced -> other -> Link display and change it